# DAX Calculate function to sumif many values across data sources

Tags: powerpivot, dax

I've been able to get the =calculate(sum(Filter,earlier) method to work on items in a single data table, but I need to extend these values into a separate table. Here is the situation:

two data sources, PoList and MinList. PoList is a list of purchases orders and open units by item barcode. MinList is a list of every store/barcode combination. I need to see total open units per bardcode in MinList. Problem is, there are many different instances of each barcode on PoList as each barcode is on many orders. Here was my approach:

1) create a new column on PoList to calculate the total units per barcode,which i did successfully using

= CALCULATE(SUM('PoList'[Open Units]), FILTER('PoList', 'PoList'[Barcode] = EARLIER ('PoList'[Barcode])))

2) Then, pull the first instance of the [Open Units] into MinList for each Barcode value. (like a vlookup, but can't create a relationship since there are multiple barcode instances on PoList

Notes: 
-Im trying to avoid creating a pivottable of PoList to eliminate duplicates. Since i can't subsequently make that pivot table, a data source, I would be creating something that would need manually updated.

Any thoughts? Again, I can get it to work in a single data source, I just need that aggregate value to be calculated in a separate data source than the one that is being analyzed to calculate the sum.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are stores included in PoList too? I'm thinking that if you add a column to both PoList and MinList, with store and barcode concatenated, you might be able to establish a relationship on those two new columns. (PoList[store/barcode]<-->MinList[store/barcode]) and use a join. Does that make sense?

Comment: yes, PoList does include Store. I tried exactly that but there are multiple instances of [store/barcode] since there are multiple orders (with different ship dates, which is NOT on MinList). So far, I've decided to pivot both lists to consolidate to a unique [store/barcode] index. Once I've done that, i have been using a simple (=) to pull the data from the pivot to the right into a table. Finally, since i just need to know the unique value from the MinList pivot that corresponds to the value in the PoList pivot, I Vlookup from MinList to PoList then Pivot the new PO table. Rough but working.